# window.open não está abrindo a popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extensão, popup, extensão

Tenho uma extensão que envia coisas pra um servidor externo por ajax post (tudo em javascript) e a resposta do send (enviada do servidor) é recebida na própria extensão. Quero colocar essa resposta em uma outra pop-up. Como posso fazer isso? Tentei com window.open(...,'_self',...) mas não deu, não abre a janela. Alguém da alguma ajuda aí? obs: não sei usar jquery

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o código que faz o POST ajax? Assim fica mais fácil visualizar o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo de extensão que permite fazer o que você pediu.

No arquivo **manifest.json** é necessário adicionar uma permissão para ter acesso ao host,
caso contrário não será possível executar o ajax. No caso, eu vou usar uma página de eco
do jsfiddle:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://jsfiddle.net/"   // aqui está a permissão necessária, para acessar o host
]
```

O resto é igualzinho ao desenvolvimento Web normal... dá até pra usar jQuery.
Eu coloquei o arquivo do jquery junto com os arquvos da extensão.
A versão usada é a que está linkada na listagem de arquivos abaixo.

### Arquivos

- [jquery-1.11.2.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js)
- manifest.json

  ```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Extensão de teste, com Ajax e Janela de Pop-up",
    "description": "Extensão de teste, com Ajax e Janela de Pop-up",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "http://jsfiddle.net/"
    ]
  }
  ```
- popup.html

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Abrindo resultado de ajax em outra tela</title>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="btn">Abrir conteúdo em outra janela</button>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- popup.js

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function() {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/',
                  data: {
                      html: '<div>Documento carregado via ajax!</div>',
                      delay: 1
                  },
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function(data){
                      var win = window.open(
                          "",
                          "Title",
                          "toolbar=no,"+
                          "location=no,"+
                          "directories=no,"+
                          "status=no,"+
                          "menubar=no,"+
                          "scrollbars=yes,"+
                          "resizable=yes,"+
                          "width=780,"+
                          "height=200,"+
                          "top="+(screen.height-400)+","+
                          "left="+(screen.width-840));
                      win.document.body.innerHTML = data;
                  },
                  error: function() {
                      alert("error: "+JSON.stringify(arguments));
                  }
              });
              return false;
          });
  });
  ```